# Is there a way to run a program in parallel while reserving some CPUs for each subprocess run with multiple cores in Bash?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have a program `NGSadmix` that can run in parallel (with the `-P` flag), but I want to run multiple iterations (1..3) of a series of 1..10 commands of `NGSadmix` commands at the same time.

I'd like to use for example 72 cores which could be divided in 3x24 cpus and then each `NGSadmix` command would have 24 cores to make the computation.

```
SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK=72
TASKCPU=$(($SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK/3))

parallel -j $SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK "NGSadmix -likes myfile.gz -P 1 -K {2} -outfiles out_{2}_it{1}.m -minMaf 0.05" ::: {1..3} ::: {1..10}
```

The command above runs 72 process in parallel but only once `-P 1` core for the `NGSadmix` program. I'm unsure that replacing `-P 1` with `-P $TASKCPU` would work as the parallel process is already taking all 72 cores to run.

Below would be a schematic representation of the division of labor I'd wish to achieve.

```
        3 different iterations that will run 10 different commands 
          24 cpus NGSadmix_iter1 process 1..10
        / 
(main) /
72 cpus-- 24 cpus NGSadmix_iter2 process 1..10
       \
        \ 
          24 cpus NGSadmix_iter3 process 1..10
```

## Update

From @Cobra_Fast's comment:

```
# test parallel
DIVTASK=2
TASKCPU=4
cd ~/Desktop
mkdir -p testpar
cd testpar
parallel -j ${DIVTASK} "echo ${TASKCPU} > test_iter.{1}_k.{2}.txt | sleep 5" ::: {1..4} ::: {1..10}
```

Comment: Just `parallel -j 3 ... -P $TASKCPU ...`?

Comment: Oh! I thought that in order to get access to the CPUs within the NGSadmix, I needed to tell parallel to pass those cores inside each subprocess.

Comment: `-j` tells `parallel` how many of your commands to run at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Would the **[quota](/questions/tagged/quota) system** impose too heavy a burden on your system?  That would eliminate specific coding.

The other option is to use "**[cpulimit](/questions/tagged/cpulimit)**", such as:

```
limit_group=70
procs=5
limit_each=$((${limit_group}/${procs}))
sudo cpulimit -p ${procID} --limit ${limit_each}
```

where limit_each is a percentage usage allowed of the overall CPU capacity.

More on that **[here](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-limit-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux-with-cpulimit/)**.